# Add seconds to a date in Clojurescript

Tags: javascript, date, clojure, clojurescript

I would like to add seconds to a date in Clojurescript. In Javascript:

```
var t = new Date();
t.setSeconds(t.getSeconds() + 10);
```

If possible without requiring a library (such as [cljs-time](https://github.com/andrewmcveigh/cljs-time)), for the simple reason that this is the only involvement I think I'm going to need with dates.

I wonder if a Javascript date can be constructed from milliseconds??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following function can be used in 2 different ways:

```
(defn add-seconds
  ([s] (add-seconds (js/Date.) s))
  ([d s] (js/Date. (+ (.getTime d) (* 1000 s)))))
```

Calling it with 1 argument will return a new date, calculated as seconds from '*now*':

```
(add-seconds 20)
;; #inst "2015-11-12T00:03:51.712-00:00" 
;; This is a Date object set 20 seconds from the time add-seconds was called
```

Calling it with 2 arguments allows to specify a start date and an offset from that date in seconds:

```
(def the-epoch (js/Date. 0))
;; This gives us a Date to use

(add-seconds the-epoch 120)
;; #inst "1970-01-01T00:02:00.000-00:00"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(defn add-seconds [js-time seconds]
  (let [given-millis (.getMilliseconds js-time)
        augmented-millis (+ (* seconds 1000) given-millis)
        res (js/Date. augmented-millis)]
    res))

(def now (js/Date.))
(def plus-20 (add-seconds now 20))
(log "Now is " now)
(log "20 secs time is " plus-20)
```

This solution works if you replace .getMilliseconds with .getTime